# How change the color of a specific word in a string? vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a problem with color of a specific word in a string.
I have my string like that:

1) i Create a table like that:

```
Dim SequenceTable As New DataTable
SequenceTable.Columns.Add("Paragraph", GetType(String))
SequenceTable.Columns.Add("Description", GetType(String))
SequenceTable.Columns.Add("ActivityName", GetType(String))
```

2)  I get value Paragraph, Description, and activityName:

```
If SequenceRow.IsNull("ActivityNumber") = False Then
                                ActivityNumber = SequenceRow.ActivityNumber
                            End If

                            If SequenceRow.IsNull("Specification") = False Then
                                Specification = SequenceRow.Specification
                            End If

                            If SequenceRow.IsNull("Dimension") = False Then
                                Paragraph = SequenceRow.Dimension
                            End If
```

3) I put all string in table:

```
                    Cell = New TableCell
                    Cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left
                    Cell.Width = Unit.Percentage(16.5)
                    Cell.CssClass = "FormatTabel"
                    Cell.Text = Description
                    Cell.Font.Size = 6
                    Cell.Wrap = True
                    Row.Cells.Add(Cell)
```

My string in description

```
Description = "Presence and pictures required. Raw data and multiload required. "
```

I want the word pictures to be red and all word to be black? But how can i set red color for word "pictures" and after put in table?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `<span/>` with formatted text using `InnerHtml`  in your cell instead `Text`

```
 Cell = New TableCell
 Cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left
 Cell.Width = Unit.Percentage(16.5)
 Cell.InnerHtml = "<span  style='color: yellow'>" + "Presence" + "</span>" + "<span  style='color: black'>" + "...black text" + "</span>";
 Cell.Font.Size = 6
 Cell.Wrap = True
 Row.Cells.Add(Cell)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string AddColor(string Text, string word string color)
{
    return Text.Replace(word, "<span color: '" + color + "'>"+word+"</span>")
}
```

Comment: you can also make this as an extension method which would be much more handy.